# window.opener function not found if there's no break point

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

The project I'm working on is a webpage that lists products. Any time you click on one, product information opens in a new window and can be manipulated and saved. The following is the ajax function to submit the form on the product information page. It should submit the form and then close the page and refresh the list on the parent page.

```
function submitForm()
{
  if(!isSubmittingForm && isValidData())
  {
    isSubmittingForm = true;
    $.ajax({
      url: 'productsubmit?com='+com+'&entry='+product.Entry(),
      data: $('#form').serialize(),
      error: function(xhr, exception) {
        isSubmittingForm = false;
      },
      success: function() {
        if (window.opener && !window.opener.closed)
          window.opener.refreshlist();
        window.close();
        isSubmittingForm = false;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

When I click on the button that calls this function, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: window.opener.refreshlist is not a function
```

However, if I put a break point in the same function, click the button, and step through it slowly I no longer get an error and the code runs exactly as expected. Even if I don't click the button and type window.opener.refreshlist() into the inspector, it runs as expected.

Any clues as to what is going on? This is all happening on Firefox.

Comment: Is there any specific reason you are using the new window instead of a modal? You will surely run into some cross browser issues with the new window (IE for sure). Also what if the client has popup blocker enabled. Then your whole UX is in the garbage. You can do exactly what you are attempting without all of the headache, by implementing a Bootstrap style modal instead. My 2¢.

Comment: Long story short: boss's orders. My task right now is just to convert some legacy code into jquery implementations. The idea is that once I'm done with this and the site is somewhat more stable, we're going to re-do it with significantly better design choices. I'd absolutely love to use modals at that point, without question.

Comment: I believe that you are running into an async issue where the function may not be defined until after the submitForm is called. You could check for this in the if statement like so: if (typeof window.opener.refreshList === 'function') else {console.log(window.opener.refreshList)} and see whats there.  If the function is truly defined before the submitForm function is called and you are still having issues, you could pass it directly to the submitForm function as a parameter and then call it directly like a callback function from the success handler. Does that make sense?

Comment: Again you will spend some time on this and maybe later realize that the solution doesnt work everywhere. You could also convince your boss that moving laterally doesnt actually take your platform anywhere. If you can spend the same amount of time on a solution that moves you forward, its better for everyone.